# How can I update Grails to 1.1 with IntelliJ IDEA 8.0.1?

Tags: ide, grails, intellij-idea

I'm running IntelliJ IDEA 8.0.1 and would like to upgrade my Grails installation to Grails 1.1 which was released today (March 10, 2009). When the upgrade is complete and I try to "run-app" my application I get the error message

> "Grails Are Not Configured".

It seems to be a known problem - but is there any work-around or fix? I'd love to upgrade to Grails 1.1, but I'm not willing to trade it for IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA 8.1 supports Grails 1.1 SDKs

Answer (score 0):

Grails 1.1 doesnt work with Intellij Idea 8.0.1.

I think the updated Intellij 8.1.1 EAP will work with Grails 1.1.  If you are having problems though try using an older version of grails (i.e. 0.6)

Answer (score -1):

I'll have to try it at home, but I wonder if you just have to point to the Grails 1.1 SDK when you create your Grails module?

I'm using the Python plug-ins in IntelliJ 8.1.  When I create a new Python module, I have to specify where to find the Python SDK.

I'm assuming that it's similar for Grails.

If the Grails plug-ins are written assuming Grails 1.0 you're screwed.  No getting around that until the plug-in is upgraded.